# Run django server in single thread only for one single url endpoint

Tags: python, django, multithreading, django-rest-framework, django-views

By default django runserver runs in multiple thread, to stop multithreading there is an option for --nothreading, but by using this all requests are handled in a single thread which impacts in server performance. I need to run an selected url endpoint with single thread and all other endpoints can execute in parallel with multiple threads.

My main motive is to handle multiple request within this endpoint in a sequence.